# peoplePickerNavigationController didSelectPerson not called for Linked Contacts

Tags: contacts, abpeoplepickerview, abpersonviewcontroller, abperson

When a user taps a Linked Contact's property using the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController - neither- 
`(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier` **or**
`(BOOL) peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier` is being called.
For regular contacts this works great.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's how I display the contacts:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty], nil];


    picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```